# Python packaging. Specify python version requirements after multiple releases

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I Have a package published on pypi and versioned as 3.0.0.

`setup.py` has never mentioned `python_requires` directive.

In release 2.5.0 there was a change which made package to be incompatible with python 2, which went unnoticed, until now.

Since 2.5.0 there were a plenty of releases of a package published on pypi.

Now, if I want to install the package using python2 - pip will install the latest release 3.0.0 which won't work.

I need pip to install version 2.4.0 - which has no compatibility issues. But how exactly can I accomplish that? (without prior knowledge of pip install package==2.4.0 - something like using pip's backtracking mechanism)

If I specify the directive `python_requires=">=3.6"` in release 3.1.0 pip will backtrack to release 3.0.0 installing package which won't work.

I can think of:

1. [cx_Oracle way](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/setup.py#L11). Raising exception in setup.py if minimal version does not match required for installation and specifying how to install correct one.
2. Create 2 new releases. One, which is essentialy 2.4.0 versioned as 3.1.0 with `python_requires=">=2.7,<3.6"` and one which is 3.0.0 versioned as 3.1.1 with `python_requires=">=3.6"`

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relatively new feature on PyPI: you could "yank" the release(s) which are incompatible with Python 2 but not correctly specifying that in the metadata.

A yanked release is a release that is always ignored by an installer, unless it is the only release that matches a version specifier (using either `==` or `===`).

See [*PEP 592 -- Adding "Yank" Support to the Simple API*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0592/) for more information. In fact, what you've described is the main scenario described in the [motivation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0592/#motivation) section of the PEP.

Comment: Very nice. If I understand it correctly, for yanking I need to make a new release with correct metadata and after that yank all releases which are "broken" for python2 for pip to backtrack to 2.4.0. Very nice, indeed. Love the solution, although we might go with re-releasing two versions, as it's also described in mentioned PEP.